# How can I find the time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

The main is to get a 6*6grid from user. The input will be stored in a 2d array. Is the time complexity should be O(n^2)? Since, I have a nested loop. But the code operates in a fixed 6 rows and 6 cols that are static. Or the time complexity should be O(n)? as the number of row and column are constant and set equals to 6.

```
public class MatrixGrid {
    private static char[][] grid = new char[6][6];
    private static int rows = 6;
    private static int cols = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixGrid matrixGrid = new MatrixGrid ();
        matrixGrid.getGridFromUser();  //get user input
        int totalHomeAreas = 0;
        int maxHomeAreaSize = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {  //---n
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {  //--n
                if (grid[i][j] == 'H') {
                    int currentSize = matrixGrid.dfs(i, j);
                    totalAreas++;
                    maxAreaSize= Math.max(maxAreaSize, currentSize );
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What's the correct time complexity?

Comment: If rows and columns are fixed at a "small number" (6 is small), then the time complexity is considered constant ie O(1). If rows and columns may vary, then it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity in all cases is based on your line `int currentSize = matrixGrid.dfs(i, j);`. Since there is not metion on it, we assume the time complexity of `matrixGrid.dfs(i, j)` is `O(1)`.

Then the time complexity of `main` is `O(n)` when we assign `n = size(grid) = rows * cols`, or `O(n^2)` when we assign `n = rows = cols`; both options are correct.

Finally, considering the constant time complexity, you should define your data constraints. If you define the constraints as `rows = 6, cols = 6`, then there is constant time complexity `O(1)`. Otherwise, if the constraints are more like `rows = n, cols = n, 0 <= n <= 10^4`, then the time complexity is `O(n^2)`, similar to the examples mentioned above.

So, the key to calculating time complexity is "the constraints of the data".

Answer (score 0):

Considering the loop iterations are constant 6*6, even though the loop is nested.

By general rule for nested loop of size i and j, the complexity would be O(i*j). Now due to constant size the iterations are finite, so the complexity would be O(6*6), which if O(1).

So resulting for constant iterations, it will be always O(1).

If your row and column size are varying but same, then it would be O(n^2), where n is number of rows/columns.

If your row and column size are varying, but not same, then it would be O(m*n), when m is number of rows and n is number of columns.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. May I ask for an example "If your row and column size are varying but same"? I a bit confuse between O(n^2) and O(m*n).

Comment: @acha: Basically, the complexity is `O(rowCount * columnCount)`, or `O(m*n)` for short, since that's how many times the innermost loop will run. Now, if we assume `rowCount` always equals `columnCount`, that means that the complexity is always `O(columnCount * columnCount)`, or `O(n*n)` for short, which is the same thing as `O(n^2)`. Whether you should describe your algorithm as `O(m*n)` or `O(n^2)` depends on whether you consider `m` and `n` to be different. (`O(m*n)` is never _wrong_ though.)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity cannot be a function of `n` for the simple reason that there is no `n` in your code.

Understand that O(n²) is not a informal expression to say that the time "grows faster than the size of the input". It really is a mathematical expression depending on the argument.